# Hibernate upgrade object from parent class to child class in JOINED inheritance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `Spring Data Jpa` and `Hibernate` on my project.

I have three tables:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
class Parent {
   String id;
   String name;
}

@Entity
class FirstChild extends Parent {
   ...
}

@Entity
class SecondChild extends Parent {
   ...
}
```

On the first step of my logic I should save `Parent object` without child type.
And on the second step I know to which `Child` table it should belong.

For example:

```
Parent parent = parentRepository.findById("id");

FirstChild firstChild = new FirstChild();
firstChild.setId(parent.getId());
firstChild.setName(parent.getName());

parentRepository.save(firstChild);
```

But when I do a Hibernate `save` it throws me exception:

```
o.h.e.i.DefaultLoadEventListener Load request found matching entity in context, but the matched entity was of an inconsistent return type; returning null
```

As I understand it doesn't know how to upgrade `entity` from parent to child type and just throws an exception because of conflict - entity with same `id` is already there.

Is there any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA is a means of mapping your Java domain model onto a relational database schema. Since there is no such thing as 'promoting a parent class to a child class' in Java, there is no support in JPA for such an operation.

That being said, you could *probably* achieve the desired behavior using a native update query. You would need to update the discriminator column (`DTYPE`) column, and insert a new row into the table corresponding to the child entity (note that in the `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy, updating the discriminator column would suffice).

A much better solution IMHO, is to delete the parent entity and insert a new child entity. If you're concerned about referential integrity, perhaps you should switch from *inheritance* to *composition*.

Comment: Actually everything looks for me as a workaround, but have the same thoughts, thanks.