# How can I change DiscriminatorValue of entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity

I would ask you about opportunity to change DiscriminatorValue for some entyty. For example I have 2 entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "user_type")
    @DiscriminatorValue("CUSTOMER")
    public class User
```

and

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "businessUser")
    @DiscriminatorValue("FOUNDER")
    public class BusinessUser extends User
```

I have repos:

```
    @NoRepositoryBean
    public interface UserBaseRepository<T extends User>  extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    T findByEmail(String email);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Repository("UserRepository")
    public interface UserRepository extends UserBaseRepository<User> {
    }

    @Transactional
    @Repository("BusinessUserRepository")
    public interface BusinessUserRepository extends UserBaseRepository<BusinessUser> {
    }
```

At first I created simple user. This entity has user_type CUSTOMER. Then I would like to expand that entity and modify it to BusinessCustomer. When I tried to do it the following: find user entity and to cast to businessUser entity I get IllegalCastException. I cannot to cast User to BusinessUser.

Help me please, How I can change user_type or or update user to businessUser.

Have a nice day,
Thanks

Comment: Ofcourse you cannot cast an `User` to a `BusinessCustomer`. It is just a user. You will have to create a new `BusinessCustomer` and save that (and fill it with the properties of the `User`).

Comment: Hi M.Denium. Yeah, right. But when I created new BusinessUser, set all fields(of course set ID from user where ID=1) and call a method userRepository.save(businessUser) I get a new record with ID=2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate upgrade object from parent class to child class in JOINED inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325473/hibernate-upgrade-object-from-parent-class-to-child-class-in-joined-inheritance)

Comment: Thanks guys, but I still try to find solution to update DTYPE column. I have DiscriminatorValue I cannot have it in my entity. So I cannot use someting like :`code`
        @Modifying
        @Query("update User u set u.user_type = :userType where u.id = :userId")
        void changeUserType(@Param("userType") String userType, @Param("userId") long userId);`code`

Comment: Of course the new "id" is different to the original one, since the original one represented a `User` and this object is not that one. Just modifying the discriminator is inadequate anyway, since you'd have to insert data into the table `businessUser` as well (since you chose JOINED strategy).

Answer (score 0):

To do something like this, I think you are forced to use a Native Query.
 Actually I do think it's not the best choice to use inheritance in the depicted situation, but that's another story.

Comment: Use a native query, bastardise the existing data, and then the JPA provider finds that there is no entry in the `businessUser` table so it can't be a `BusinessUser` after all ...

Comment: That's easy, you s add also a row in the businessUser table

Comment: hackety hack hack. Why are they using JPA if they do that?

Comment: As I wrote in the original post, I would think a bit better if inheritance should be used at all. But if you want to solve the problem in the given situation there is no way left then using native queries

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had the same issue. I tried couple of things before succeeding in making it work. I read many people arguing that this is bad case of inheritance. In my case I had inheritance for different states of the same object, so I wanted to be able to change the state. Deleting and recreating was not a good choice, because I have relationships with other tables that I wanted maintained.

Wrote a modifying query in JPA and it worked.

```
@Modifying
@Query("Update ParentType pt " +
        "SET pt.ColumnType = \'new_value\' " +
        "WHERE pt.id= :id")
void updateType(Long id);
```

Beware that Modifying queries can only return void or int.

Answer (score -1):

You could make a `Service` where you can *promote* your user...

```
public BusinessUser promote(User user) {
    BusinessUser businessUser = new BusinessUser();
    businessUser.setId(user.getId());
    businessUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    userRepository.delete(user);
    return businessUserRepository.save(businessUser);
}
```

If want the promoted user still has the original ID then **DO NOT** use `@GeneratedValue` and you need to delete the original user before you save the promoted user.